# Redis ETIMEDOUT gitlab ci

Tags: node.js, redis, gitlab, bullmq

After added **bullmq** to the project stack, I started to face with problem in gitlab CI pipelines, to be more concrete in the integration tests, looks like something wrong with redis because application cannot connect to the redis - **ioredis** library thrown **ETIMEDOUT** error - and it happens only in the gitlab jobs, on the production and dev environments I didn't face with this error.

```yaml
    .test_integration:
          extends:
            - .cache
            - .install-deps
            - .review
          variables:
            GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
            GIT_SUBMODULE_UPDATE_FLAGS: --remote --no-single-branch
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
            POSTGRES_DB: test_integration
            POSTGRES_HOST: db
            POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
            DATABASE_HOST: db
            DATABASE_NAME: test_integration
            AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: eu-west-1
            SERVICES: s3
            DATA_DIR: /tmp/localstack/data
            S3_URL: http://localstack:4566
            IMAGES_S3_BUCKET: images-integration
            FILES_S3_BUCKET: files-integration
            KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
            ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,INTERNAL://localhost:9093
            LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9093
            SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
            INTER_BROKER: INTERNAL
            KAFKA_ALLOW_AUTO_TOPIC_CREATION: 'true'
            REDIS_HOST: redis
            REDIS_PORT: 6379
            CI_DEBUG_SERVICES: 'true'
          services:
            - name: postgres:13.6-alpine
              alias: db
            - name: localstack/localstack:0.14.2
              alias: localstack
            - name: krisgeus/docker-kafka
              alias: kafka
            - name: redis:7.0.10-alpine
              command: ['redis-server', '--save', '""', '--appendonly', 'no']
              alias: redis
          stage: test
          image: node:16.15.0-alpine
          environment:
            action: prepare
          coverage: '/^Statements\s*:\s*([^%]+)/'
          artifacts:
            when: always
            reports:
              coverage_report:
                coverage_format: cobertura
                path: coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml
              junit:
                - junit.xml
          needs:
            - review-build
```

What I did:

1. Removed persistence on disk via adding command to the gitlab job - `['redis-server', '--save', '""', '--appendonly', 'no']`
2. Added debug for service containers, but it doesn't show me any
   errors with redis, so I assume that redis container is live, but why application cannot connect to it, it's a mystery

Errors in the logs:

-

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
           at Socket.<anonymous> (node_modules/ioredis/built/Redis.js:170:41)
           at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28)
           at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
           at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
           at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:516:8)
           at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
           at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
         errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
         code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
         syscall: 'connect'
       }
```

- `WARNING: Service redis:7.0.10-alpine is already created. Ignoring.`